# Remove missing values in r

Tags: r

I am trying to remove missing values in r:

code:

```
na.omit(x)
```

which gives the output omitted 56 entries.

```
typeof(x)
```

returns "double"

Now again when I check with the following function it returns true.

```
anyNA(x)
```

I am new to R, and am not sure what is going wrong. any suggestions would be fine.

Comment: You might want to read some introductory tutorial in R so you know that this applies to almost any operation in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to update the object after applying the function..  Otherwise, it wouldn't change the values stored in the object

```
x <- na.omit(x)
anyNA(x)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Suppose, if we wanted to update the values in the object without doing the `<-`, then we can use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` which does this

```
library(magrittr)
x %<>%
  na.omit()

anyNA(x)
#[1] FALSE
```

#### data

```
x <- c(NA, 1:3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this -

```html
new_table <- na.omit(df)
```

Comment: Hey there, isn't this the same as the accepted answer?